# How to fix top element under Appbar and the rest scroll-able?

Tags: html, css, mudblazor

I would like to have a fixed card above my scrollable cards.

I have tried with different settings of overflow and position:fixed but I could not achieve the followings:

- top card shall be fixed
- below cards shall be scrollable without specifying the height

My problem is I would like the container for the list of Card would fill the rest space without specifying the height of the container with bottom-padding.

what i have tried:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEwdlGYyoWVMwFtI

```
<MudAppBar Color="Color.Primary" Fixed="true" >
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" />
    <MudSpacer />
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.GitHub" Color="Color.Inherit" />
</MudAppBar>

<MudGrid Spacing="2" Style="margin-top:86px;">
    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudCard>
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudText>Story of the day</MudText>
                <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</MudText>
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Text" Color="Color.Primary">Learn More</MudButton>
            </MudCardActions>
        </MudCard>
    </MudItem>

    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudDivider></MudDivider>
    </MudItem>

    <div class="pa-3 overflow-scroll" style="height:200px; width:100%">
        @for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            <MudItem xs="12">
                <MudCard>
                    <MudCardContent>
                        <MudText>Story of the day</MudText>
                        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</MudText>
                    </MudCardContent>
                    <MudCardActions>
                        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Text" Color="Color.Primary">Learn More</MudButton>
                    </MudCardActions>
                </MudCard>
            </MudItem>
        }
    </div>
    
</MudGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is it's working as you described in your snippet. Here's a snippet with some slight adjustments, the MudItem can be used as the overflow wrapper so no need to create an additional div. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wamdPckyBFWikLbn

Comment: My problem is I would like the container for the list of Card would fill the rest space without specifying the height of the container with bottom-padding.

Comment: if you want the list of cards container to be fixed to the window/screen height then use vh like in my snippet. You will definitely need to use height if you want to contain it to the same screen/window.

Comment: or do some inline calculations based on the number of items like so. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GaQRFQkyVIbNSIRg

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, there is no way just to say the container fits the rests and scroll? The calculation is not really ideal because in the MudCard I will add content which makes each Card different heights.

Comment: nope there needs to be a boundary (e.g. height) for the DOM to know when to start a scroll.

Comment: What about if I add a fix footer at the bottom of the page, as margin and say height 100% wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max-height` to set the boundary for the scroll to start.

```
<MudAppBar Color="Color.Primary" Fixed="true" >
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" />
    <MudSpacer />
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.GitHub" Color="Color.Inherit" />
</MudAppBar>

<MudGrid Spacing="2" Style="margin-top:86px;"> 
    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudCard>
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudText>Story of the day</MudText>
                <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</MudText>
            </MudCardContent>
            <MudCardActions>
                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Text" Color="Color.Primary">Learn More</MudButton>
            </MudCardActions>
        </MudCard>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12">
        <MudDivider></MudDivider>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" Class="overflow-auto" Style="max-height:60vh;">
        @foreach(var item in _items)
        {
                <MudCard Class="ma-2">
                    <MudCardContent>
                        <MudText>Card:@item </MudText>
                        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</MudText>
                    </MudCardContent>
                    <MudCardActions>
                        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Text" Color="Color.Primary">Learn More</MudButton>
                    </MudCardActions>
                </MudCard>
        }
    
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>

<MudButton Class="mt-4" OnClick="HandleClick" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Success">Add item</MudButton>
@code{
    List<string> _items = new(){"1"};

    void HandleClick()
    {
        _items.Add($"{_items.Count}");
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wacnbmOTotOeHFet)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible the scrolling start when the elements reached the bottom of the page and not with 60vh?

Comment: You can play around with the values for vh +- units